# MsgId: MERR-26612

Tags: loadrunner

When replaying my script in vugen I get the error:
Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "and some url" [MsgId: MER-26612]]

I could mantion that we are using a security string at the end og the initail url in loadrunner vugen scripting when recording and that this url changes when logged in to the webapp (we are doing this to avoid opensso problems, it is not implemented yet).

Can anybody tell me what this error message means?

Cheers
Magnus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you are passing data that either the system does not know how to process or is inappropriate given the context of the previous request/response pair.   Here are the typical reasons

- Unhandled/mishandled Dynamic data related to session, state, time or business process data
- Not checking for expected results for each request/response set and then branching the code as appropriate when an unexpcted response set appears.    Without checking, so long as the page itself manifests an HTTP 200, even if the content of the page is totally out of focus for the business process to continue then the script will continue to the next page.  It is likely on the next or Next ++ that you get an HTTP 500 in this case.

In short, barring an odd under load condition, this is all directly related to poor script development practices.

Comment: one more thing could you show me how tio capture a value from a page and checking for expected results? As U say in you comment. Just a small example including what LR function as in web_xxx to capture an some other to check for expected result.

Comment: See your LoadRunner training material surrounding web_reg_find().   Please note you are validating against the HTTP stream and not against the GUI, so you must be versed in validating against the HTML source and not a GUI event.

Answer (score 0):

Magnus,

This error message is exactly what it says "Internal Server Error". This is a problem with the application not liking your query. I suggest that you do this manually, then work out what is different with your LoadRunner requests.

Remember, you are just using LoadRunner as a tool to simulate HTTP requests. If your requests aren't correct, then either manually or using a tool you will get this error.

I suggest you spend some time with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [HTTP Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/), or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what is different between the requests via the browser, and the requests made via LoadRunner.