# LoadRunner ajax field

Tags: ajax, loadrunner

I record a script on a webpage that contains a textfield that I typically put in zip codes snd another field is updated based on the zipcode numbers I type in. 
When replaying the svript I get errors. I think my problem has to do with that the script being generated contains one web_submit_data for each number I put in as part of the zip code.

Here is the error msg I get at the after the first web_submit_data:

Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "and some url" [MsgId: MER-26612]]

Does someone know this problem and a possible solution?
It is described here to:

http://www.myloadtest.com/scripting-exercise-a-basic-ajax-application/

Thank you!

---

My code is below. It is recorder using the web/http protocol and it is recording when I type into a selfpopulating field/autocomplete field, so when I type 7000 into the zipcode field LR generates one web_submit_data for each nubmer i type in. I do not know if that is the problem dough.

Action()
{

```
web_url("nav_security_check", 
    "URL=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/nav_security_check?id=12345678910", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=img/nav_logo.gif", "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

lr_think_time(4);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.0-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t2.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType", "Value=radio11", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

lr_think_time(4);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_2", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType-alternativAdressePanel-norskAlternativPostnummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t3.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=7", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_3", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType-alternativAdressePanel-norskAlternativPostnummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t4.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=70", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_4", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType-alternativAdressePanel-norskAlternativPostnummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t5.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=700", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_5", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType-alternativAdressePanel-norskAlternativPostnummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t6.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=7000", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_6", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType-alternativAdressePanel-norskAlternativPostnummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t7.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=7000", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_7", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.2-brukerprofil~skjema-valgtAdresseType-alternativAdressePanel-norskAlternativPostnummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t8.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=7000", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

lr_think_time(6);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_8", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-brukerprofil~skjema-kontonummer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/xml", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t9.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=kontonummer", "Value=62281154546", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

web_submit_data("brukerprofil_9", 
    "Action=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0-1.IFormSubmitListener-brukerprofil~skjema", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=http://someurl.local:8080/brukerprofil/brukerprofil?0", 
    "Snapshot=t10.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=brukerprofil-skjema_hf_0", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType", "Value=radio11", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostAdresse1", "Value=Nedgata 2", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostAdresse2", "Value=Postboks 2", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostAdresse3", "Value=Sentrum 123", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=valgtAdresseType:alternativAdressePanel:norskAlternativPostnummer", "Value=7000", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=kontonummer", "Value=62281154546", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=mobilpanel:landkode", "Value=47", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=mobilpanel:nummer", "Value=98765432", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=telefonnummerpanel:landkode", "Value=47", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=telefonnummerpanel:nummer", "Value=22225555", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ekstra-telefonnummerpanel:landkode", "Value=46", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=ekstra-telefonnummerpanel:nummer", "Value=11223344", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=epost", "Value=per.hansen@hjemme.no", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that you have unhandled dynamic data.   This is very much related to your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512243/msgid-merr-26612/13531209#13531209).   Looking at the requests you have noted there are several items that stick out as likely unhandled elements of Dynamic data and one security ID that seems completely faked.

Record your busines process 2-3 times.   Use WinDiff (Included with LoadRunner) or another file DIFF tool that you like to identify the differences between the recordings.   The dynamic elements should literally jump off the page as differences between the recordings.   You will need to handle these dynamic elements appropriately if you wish your script to continue.

Also, Testing 101 housekeeping items, for each step there is an expected result.  Conspicuously absent in your code is any sort of check for a correct expected result.   In such a case it's quite easy for an HTTP 200 status page to be returned which is completely out of context for your business process, but when allows your script to continue.  In such a condition where you have "come off the tracks" and do not know if due to the lack of checking for expected results it is a 100% certainty that you will hit an HTTP 500 within 1-2 request sets.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP error 500 is generated when the server has an internal error such as a PHP script gone wrong. I can provide help if you could just post the code that makes the ajax request and the file it is fetching (just the contents is fine).

Answer (score 0):

Magnus, may I suggest you stop using the record button and look into what is happening at the HTTP level rather than relying on a tool to pick up the requests.

I suggest you spend some time with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [HTTP Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/), or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what the application is actually doing first.

You can not automate something if you don't know what happens when you do it manually.